# Graphics Card for Dell Optiplex 755

Tags: graphics-card, dell-optiplex

I am absolutely not up to date when it comes to hardware. I have this Dell Optiplex 755 that only has an onboard D-Sub output, but I want to use the machine to watch videos on a large Samsung LCD TV.

Now the LCD comes with a D-Sub input but I'd rather use a HDMI connection so I'd need a new graphics card. The case is however smaller than computers I am used to seeing, so what graphics card do I need to buy for the machine? The slots at the rear of the case only measure 7cm or less.

[image]

Note that I'm asking for **the term** used for the graphics card and not actually the graphics card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of **low profile** (that's the key phrase to use when searching) cards that will fit in that case.  Unfortunately, those Optiplex's come with small power supplies. I have a full size one I am looking at and it has 305w supply so the smaller form factor one you have pictured probably has a lower wattage than my full tower. Sadly I don't have any of the slim 755's but I do have slim Optilex 330's, gx620's, and 745's they all have 280 watt power supplies. I remember having issues with 8600gt's with those power supplies the best one I have successfully got to work is the NVidia 8400gs. I can guarantee they will work with that case with that power supply, they are not the best cards but if you just want dual display's it will work fine.

EDIT: you might want to check to see if the slim 755 has the 280w supply, I'm 90% sure it does, but if it has a 305w you might be able to get a better card working.